# How to implement http keep-alive attribute with select()

Tags: c, sockets, keep-alive

My task is to implement simple HTTP on sockets. I should implement http keep-alive attribute. I want to use `select()` for this purpose, but I can't understand to implement this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The `select` function is not needed for keep-alive, it's just a way of polling  descriptors for possible input. All you really need for keep-alive is to simply not close the socket after each request. As for how to use `select`, there are many tutorials and examples all over the Internet.

Comment: Do I need use select() if I have multiple connections?

Comment: It depends on how you handle the connections. Do you use one process per connection or one thread per connection? Then you don't need to use `select` or polling. Do you use a single process and a single thread that needs to multiplex between all connections? Then you might need something like `select`.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I use fork() to create new process for every new request. So I don't need to use select().